# Facebook SDK for React Native on Android isn't installed on the Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I've installed react-native-fbsdk successfully on my existing react native project and was able to import a login button from facebook and track the automatic events on the Events tracker on the website for my facebook app both for iOS and Android. But what i'm more interested in is setting up codeless events instead of manually writing the events myself. But when I try to set up the codeless events online on the website, it shows that I've not installed the facebook sdk for android and it's installed for iOS. [As shown  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLUV1.png)

And every time I try to follow the upgrading instructions, it's still doesn't want to verify that I upgraded the SDK for android.
[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAfzJ.png)

I've followed all the installation instructions correctly based on how I can use the login button from facebook and see the events triggered in the Test Events panel for my app on the website. So i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Info:
React-native version: 0.61.5,
Expokit version:36,
react-native-fbsdk version :^1.1.2,

Comment: Hey there I am also facing the same issue in IOS. In android it's successful but in IOS its giving that it not setup. How to get rid of this any solution?